# How to define a global PatternLayout for log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Is it possible to define a (named) `PatternLayout` within a `log4j2.xml` configuration file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration status="ERROR">
    <appenders>
      <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
      </Console>

      <File name="DEBUG_FILE" fileName="debug.txt">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
      </File>
    </appenders>

    <loggers>
      <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_FILE" />
      </root>
    </loggers> 

</configuration>
```

In this example the `PatternLayout` is repeated. Could I define it somehow globally with a name, and then just use the name reference to set the pattern for each appender?

Comment: You might also have a look to the property usage in the log4j2.xml in the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819376/log4j2-rollingfile-appender-add-custom-info-at-the-start-of-each-logfile/20979314#20979314).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

define:

```
    <Properties>
        <property name="path">c:/logs/</property>
    </Properties>
```

use:

```
   <RollingFile fileName="${path}mylog.log"
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: Well, the question was: how to define global properties. My answer is: how to define a gobal property ;)

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I have suggested an edit to the answer to use the code from the example in the question, so the connection becomes clear.

Answer (score 18):

According to the official [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution), you can define a "property" and reuse its value.

In this case, I am defining the `appenderPatternLayout` property.

Here the full code (tested with Log4J 2.3) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>

    <Properties>
        <Property name="appenderPatternLayout">%d %-5p %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${appenderPatternLayout}" />
        </Console>
        <File name="DEBUG_FILE" fileName="debug.txt">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${appenderPatternLayout}" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="DEBUG_FILE" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers> 
</Configuration>
```