# Log files not getting cleared of old log entries during daily rollover

Tags: log4j2

We are using log4j2.3 on Apache Tomcat. We recently upgraded from log4j1.2 to log4j2.0. It is working fine except for one issue. We use the RollingFile Appender to rollover the log files daily. The files rollover right after midnight as expected, but the current log file does not get cleared of the log entries from the previous day. We end up with a log files that keep growing in size and contain entries from all previous days as well.

This is our rolling file Appender configuration:

Any ideas?

Comment: <RollingFile name="D" fileName="${fileLocation}/${D-filename}" filePattern="${fileLocation}/${D-filename}.%d{yyyyMMdd}" append="true">
 <PatternLayout pattern="${logMsgPattern}"/>
  <Policies>
   <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" interval="1"/>
  </Policies>
</RollingFile>

Answer (score 1):

Found the following JIRA that appeared to describe the problem I am seeing as well:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-904?jql=project%20%3D%20LOG4J2%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC

Also, adopted the solution described in the following question with a slight change to overwrite the file after rollover and that has fixed my problem:

[Log4j2 RollingFile Appender - add custom info at the start of each logfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819376/log4j2-rollingfile-appender-add-custom-info-at-the-start-of-each-logfile)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the default rollover strategy. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DefaultRolloverStrategy

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that Alan. I tried that and it worked correctly for the first two days. But on today's rollover, it left yesterday's content in today's log file and is appending to it. This is my new configuration. Any ideas:

Comment: <RollingFile name="AR" fileName="${fileLocation}/${AR-filename}" filePattern="${fileLocation}/${AR-filename}-%i.%d{yyyyMMdd}" append="true">
   <PatternLayout pattern="${logMsgPattern}"/>
   <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" interval="1"/>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
   </Policies>
  </RollingFile>

Comment: Try adding the default Rollover strategy ` <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3"/>` that will allow only 3 files per day, use whatever number you want.

Comment: Sorry attaching the full configuration showing the default rollover strategy. I had it with max of 10. (Sorry, every time I press enter for a newline, it saves the comment).   <RollingFile name="D" fileName="${fileLocation}/${D-filename}" filePattern="${fileLocation}/${D-filename}-%i.%d{yyyyMMdd}" append="true">
   <PatternLayout pattern="${logMsgPattern}"/>
   <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" interval="1"/>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
   </Policies>
  </RollingFile>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>

Comment: Also i would remove modulate=true, i don't really think it is necessary for doing daily rollovers. The modulate option could cause it to wait to do the rollover.

Comment: Also another tip, to quickly test how this works. Run some code that creates some logs, then change your system time to the next day and run it again. You can see how it decides to do the rollovers quickly instead of having to wait a few days.

Comment: or you could add the minute unit to your date pattern and it would try to rollover every minute instead of day (the rollover unit is the smallest unit available in the date pattern of filePattern)

Comment: Appreciate your responses Alan. I have tried with modulate=false as well. The problem is it works fine for a couple of days, but starts exhibiting the problem after 2 or 3 days of continuous operation. I am afraid changing the system clock would make it work for one day, but not necessarily fix the problem. I might have to make a code change to force clearing the file by myself rather than relying on the log4j framework. Any other suggestions? (I tried hourly rollover as well and that worked fine for the first few hours. Then when I set it to 12 hour rollover it started showing the problem)

Comment: No problem, Honestly i can't really think of why this would occur and haven't experienced it myself. My only other suggestion would be to maybe checkout the JIRA for log4j2 and see if anyone else has had this problem. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel